# GCC 4.2.1 darwin Avoid duplicate symbols

Tags: iphone, gcc

I'm building application for iPhone OS 3.0
Due to bug in GCC 4.2.1 I'm adding -all_load flag to linker, to build it on iPhone OS 3.0
But then I get 
duplicate symbol _fill_fopen_filefunc in /Users/TMC2/Programming/Client/test/build/Debug-iphoneos/test.a(ioapi.o) and /Users/TMC2/Programming/Client/test/build/Debug-iphoneos/test.a(ioapi.o)

How to avoid duplicate symbols?
Andy suggestions?

Comment: I'm running into this exact issue. It appears to be a bug with the -all_load flag.

Answer (score 1):

Rerun the linker command omitting one of the libraries and see what happens.  This is fairly straight forward if you pipe the build output to a file and just edit the linker statement.

Since you are building with source it is worth a try to replace one of the source files that generate ioapi.o with something containing only whitespace.  Static libraries do not need to resolve their symbols until something links a loadable module from them.

Your mileage may vary on either of these.

Comment: If you notice, the same library and object inside of that library is referred to twice. I'm running into this same issue and it only crops up when -all_load is specified.